# How can i rewrite TierPrice Block in Magento2

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I am facing one issue in block rewrite.
I am trying to rewrite 
`app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`
I want to Call my own `tier_prices.phtml`

```
<code>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="group_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/group_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/option.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
</code>
```

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose package:Learning and module: Custom

Module.xml looks like

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_Custom" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And then create a layout xml following path -> **app/code/Learning/Custom/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Learning_Custom::product/price/tier_prices.phtml
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Create template inside your module or copy base template file inside your module path should be -> 
**app/code/Learning/Custom/view/frontend/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not working.

Comment: It's tested code. Could you run following command after module creation -> php bin/magento setup:upgrade . Clear magento cache.

Comment: Yes, Its working after command run.

Comment: not working for me. has this method changed in latest magento ?

Comment: Works for me. I would like to do it only on certain pages though..

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
<referenceBlock name='contactForm'>
    <action method='setTemplate'>
        <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendorname_Modulename::form_new.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```